# httpHandler works for virtual directory but not similarly configured website

Tags: iis-6, httphandler, virtual-directory

I am setting up a 3rd party website which makes heavy use of httpHandlers. When configured as a virtual directory under Default Site on a 2003/IIS6 machine, everything works as expected. When configured as a standalone site on the same machine, pointing to the same directory and web.config however, httpHandlers do not work (404).

I have tried various changes to the path values of the handler's  tags with no results. The pages themselves, and the application's code, all seem to execute find within the standalone site.

Any obvious things I might be missing?

Comment: Can you post the relevant portion of your web.config?

Comment: very sorry, did not see your comment - getting used to the interface here.

Answer (score 1):

Found my own answer, was a very simple thing.

An installer package had installed the virtual directory version of the site, and it had taken care of adding the file extension mappings. The standalone was manually configured and as such, I missed adding the mappings.

Resolved.